# I can't use Spread into mapStateToProps [React Native]

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux

[I got this error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yEHgk.png)

I know lots of questions are there on this error, but in my case, i can't use spread inside `mapStateToProps`, While in my previous case, I can use spread inside `mapStateToProps`. can anybody tell me about this error?

this is my code by the way

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
  const IncomeVal = _.map(state.IncomeVal, (val, uid) => {
      return { ...val, uid };
  });

   return { IncomeVal };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { ValueIncome })(PageHome);
```

Comment: Can you please just post that error message here in your question?
That will be more helpful in finding the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying to return a props object with the same properties as the state.IncomeVal.val object and also a property for state.IncomeVal.uid? Please try this:

```
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
     ...state.IncomeVal.val,
     uid: state.IncomeVal.uid
  });
```

Here is a [plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/9rjKnylyIOqqaS4kGCSk?p=preview) demonstrating the js spread operator.

Comment: Thanks for your Advice, but i've found my mistake, my Mistake is i use firebase for database and i put my data with syntax `update`, that is my mistake, i should use syntax `push`, because `push` will create a new child with some uniq Id, and that's uniq id will be an Object., my mistake use `update` that just enter my data without uniq id, and the result is just array in my database.